# How to get narrower type inference for nested object properties?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

Here is a simplified example of a schema library I am working on ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2AeAKlCAPYCNAEwGcpTgAnASzQHMoBeC6u+gGigDVmok0AazRwA7mgB8fAN4AoKAqh1CVNAEMEWcBABcULPMUA3DUl09ZAX1mzQkfWoBGCaCzmKoAbQDGiVGj1KWgYAXT14ZHQrGztoACUxbFwCIjIHZwgpN0MFYjVgNT13D0VPGCU0KEEIEDgAM30w-TKQzwByE2QINpCcqGtrW20oADlURwgqCP8+afQMNuU2rjRxyYkh+wBlNgY5ypZ9haDl1mD6DdioACE4RAg1NH3Zv3m2xzuEU4-7x8vhuIQOqTIjeCBHHD4QgkchYJwuPhwjJZWCvTBtKhA04JUTYCRSABkUGkUAKGT0OEGVwAYnckQjsh41N5gDQjOZbr8nmi+mBaHBaKA9GMUBMpjyqcNrmoqPTXMS+uoUOYdud9n06nc9IDgZi0GCjrS4HKNpL7AAFGjeQT7UhJKGpWHwiBcfZaewOmGoyKSPiW60YPpYDh9YolLzlOhVGr1RoUlrJaFpN3DAD8sCgejQEHZVD6lk81VqDSwvUJCo8PjRgV29CaKcg0VkdQELJocEqvh91KocBQOpB+ogcsDHkhKS9cpDHh1EXInrS-ptaLtwagA71BrRKKXtuwXA3oPB2+nilniBGamVicd0eL66Bc74Rdj54QpFPCjfN69b9InjfS9lRCPg-wAx8LyvCAQk-B86jlH80jfdoyRcHpQIghAUOdHpYJ1OUIiA6AF3IF8Gnw51nxjcigTlWQJAACkxXUj32bVMKIrhmMHMECOrOC+IQIiAEoK0UbjN2PH0+gko9BP8Jsu38Hs+0PIcR2lWVnUYtpNTgU42mZVl2TaUTFAAenMngNBoYhZCU9AVP7IEeOHZ0ME0k0GN0u4DL5dtBRAUyFEs6yEFs+y0SctTePczztO8vSDNEXsGGCjxQq2AALOAkAQYg0DaYAoAmKBOlsoA)):

```js
type Column<T extends string = string, V = unknown> = {
    internalType: T
    value: V
}

type Table = {
    [column: string]: Column
}

type Row<T extends Table> = {
    data: {
        [C in keyof T]: T[C]['value']
    }
}

type NumberColumn = Column<'int', number>
type StringColumn = Column<'str', string>
type BooleanColumn = Column<'bool', boolean>
type ReferenceColumn<T extends Table = Table> = Column<'ref', Row<T>> & { table: T }

type FooTable = {
    active: BooleanColumn
    priority: NumberColumn
}

type BarTable = {
    name: StringColumn
    foo: ReferenceColumn<FooTable>
}

type PickColumns<T extends Table, ColumnType extends Column> = Pick<
    T,
    {
        [C in keyof T]: T[C] extends ColumnType ? C : never
    }[keyof T]
> & {
    [column: string]: ColumnType
}

function columnFromReferenceTable<
    T extends Table,
    RefCols extends PickColumns<T, ReferenceColumn> = PickColumns<T, ReferenceColumn>,
    RefColName extends keyof RefCols = keyof RefCols,
    RefCol extends RefCols[RefColName] = RefCols[RefColName],
    RefTable extends RefCol['table'] = RefCol['table'],
    RefTableColName extends keyof RefTable = keyof RefTable
>(referenceColumn: RefColName, referenceTableColumn: RefTableColName) {
    referenceColumn
    referenceTableColumn
}

columnFromReferenceTable<BarTable>('foo', 'active')    // Valid
columnFromReferenceTable<BarTable>('foo', 'priority')  // Valid
columnFromReferenceTable<BarTable>('foo', 'wrong')     // Shouldn't be valid
```

Basically there are table schemas that might have columns which reference other table schemas. The goal is to have a function that takes two strings, where the first string is the name of a reference column from one table, and the second string is the name of any column on the other table being referenced.

The problem is: I can't get the string value of the second argument to be constrained properly. The first argument is constrained correctly, but the second argument can be any string value, which is not correct.

I tried to simplify the example as much as possible without being too contrived. I know the type signature of the function is needlessly verbose, but was hoping it might help readers understand how I'm trying to navigate the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another answer pointed out, my issue is due to TypeScript's current lack of [partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for type arguments. Since `BarTable` is being passed as a type argument without the others, the default types are used which are less constrained.

Instead of the currying solution provided by the other answer, I have opted for a different solution that avoids the partial type inference issue altogether by passing the table in as an object, which enables full inference of all type arguments:

```js
function columnFromReferenceTable<
    T extends Table,
    RefCols extends PickColumns<T, ReferenceColumn> = PickColumns<T, ReferenceColumn>,
    RefColName extends keyof RefCols = keyof RefCols,
    RefCol extends RefCols[RefColName] = RefCols[RefColName],
    RefTable extends RefCol['table'] = RefCol['table'],
    RefTableColName extends keyof RefTable = keyof RefTable
>(table: T, referenceColumn: RefColName, referenceTableColumn: RefTableColName) {
    table
    referenceColumn
    referenceTableColumn
}

const barTable = {} as BarTable

columnFromReferenceTable(barTable, 'foo', 'active')    // Valid
columnFromReferenceTable(barTable, 'foo', 'priority')  // Valid
columnFromReferenceTable(barTable, 'foo', 'wrong')     // Shouldn't be valid
```

In my library, tables are already objects anyway so this design provides better DX than currying. ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2AeAKlCAPYCNAEwGcpTgAnASzQHMoBeC6u+gGigDVmok0AazRwA7mgB8fAN4AoKAqh1CVNAEMEWcBABcULPMUA3DUl09ZAX1mzQkfWoBGCaCzmKoAbQDGiVGj1KWgYAXT14ZHQrGztoACUxbFwCIjIHZwgpN0MFYjVgNT13D0VPGCU0KEEIEDgAM30w-TKQzwByE2QINpCcqGtrW20oADlURwgqCP8+afQMNuU2rjRxyYkh+wBlNgY5ypZ9haDl1mD6DdioACE4RAg1NH3Zv3m2xzuEU4-7x8vhuIQOqTIjeCBHHD4QgkchYJwuPhwjJZWCvTBtKhA04JUTYCRSABkUGkUAKGT0OEGVwAYnckQjsh41N5gDQjOZbr8nmi+mBaHBaKA9GMUBMpjyqcNrmoqPTXMS+uoUOYdud9n06nc9IDgZi0GCjrS4HKNpL7AAFGjeQT7UhJKGpWHwiBcfZaewOmGoyKSPiW60YPpYDh9YolLzlOhVGr1RoUlrJaFpN3DAD8sCgejQEHZVD6lk81VqDSwvUJCo8PjRgV29CaKcg0VkdQELJocEqvh91KocBQOpB+ogcsDHkhKS9cpDHh1EXInrS-ptaLtwagA71BrRKKXtuwXA3oPB2+nilniBGamVicd0eL66Bc74Rdj54QpFPCjfN69b9InjfS9lRCPg-wAx8LyvCAQk-B86jlH80jfdoyRcHpQIghAUOdHpYJ1OUIiA6AF3IF8Gnw51nxjcigTlWQJAAClQ8w10xXUj32bVMKIrg2MHMECOrODBIQIiAEoK0UZi+j4zdjx9GSgX44dnXVQZfDQSgoEcGUELcSwoDUchpVlZ0bC7fwez7Q8hzlBidNMjIuDaTU4FONpmVZdk2gkxQAHo-J4DQaGIWQLPQKz+yUuS7IcqcoBcu53L5dtBRAHyFACoKEBCsK0UimyBOdezdOdZzXPc0RewYDKPCyrYAAs4CQBBiDQNpgG06BOhCoA))

Answer (score 2):

Since partial type inference is not supported, when you call your function with only one generic parameter, the defaults for the others are used instead, which as you observed, leads to basically no type-checking for your example.

The way we typically get around this is to *curry* the function:

```
function columnFromReferenceTable<T extends Table>() {
    return function <
        RefCols extends PickColumns<T, ReferenceColumn> = PickColumns<T, ReferenceColumn>,
        RefColName extends keyof RefCols = keyof RefCols,
        RefCol extends RefCols[RefColName] = RefCols[RefColName],
        RefTable extends RefCol["table"] = RefCol["table"],
        RefTableColName extends keyof RefTable = keyof RefTable
    >(referenceColumn: RefColName, referenceTableColumn: RefTableColName) {
        referenceColumn;
        referenceTableColumn;
    };
}
```

So slide in another pair of parentheses, and we're good to go:

```
columnFromReferenceTable<BarTable>()("foo", "active");
columnFromReferenceTable<BarTable>()("foo", "priority");
columnFromReferenceTable<BarTable>()("foo", "wrong"); // errors
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2AeAKlCAPYCNAEwGcpTgAnASzQHMoBeC6u+gGigDVmok0AazRwA7mgB8fAN4AoKAqh1CVNAEMEWcBABcULAG55igG4akunkYC+R2aEj61AIwTQWcxVADaAY0SoaHqUtAwAunrwyOg2dg7QAEpi2LgERGROrhBSHsYKxGrAanqeXoreMEpoUIIQIHAAZvoR+hVh3gBEZsgQHWFGXrayQ-baUAByqM4QVFGBfHPoGB3KHVxoUzMSRvFQAMpsDIvVLMfLIWusofTbo44AQnCIEGpoxwsBSx3OTwiXP89XrddgkIA0ZkRfBAzjh8IQSOQsC43HwkVkcrBPpgOlQwZckqJsBIpAAyKDSKBFLJ6HAjXYAMSeaJRuS8al8wBoJksj0BbyxA0UYFocFooD0kxQ01mAuGcTG9zUVGZ7nJeSg6hQlgO12OgoUDSeelB4NxaChZ0ZcBVtzpYwACjRfIJjqQUnD0ojkRAuMctI4PQjMdFJHxHc6MOqsBx1aUyj5KnQanVGs0aW1UvCMn6xgB+WBQPRoCDcqj6qDWby1epNLBhWSktVePxY4KHegtHOQWKyWQNAQcmhwar+EP0qhwFAmiHmiAq91pIM2gAUAEom4pccAkKooP3zZzh1BI-GFCaouRAxlwy6sW7o1Bp2aLViMTfXdguE-IdDXzHT4+YJROMahapmnrJjWgENBefDVqm56IKQ-6nohCDgUGaGkN4aEgVqYR8FhOFAYgeEQGEKHxiaKoYRkaGdFSbh9IRJEIAx3p9JRZTUd6wGgdAV7kPBTQ8VkcEpiJYIquqEjLripo-scxqsWRXDyTOUIqkp0FaaR-HrnGZTqc+v4huWXjGT+ulmeqQzWL2o6BOOk7frO86Ksq3qyauy4dIacCXB07KctyHSrkYjnoM5U5ghpc7ehgHkrj5flPIFwpDmKIBhRFWLRa5mkJUlXlrr5-mBaIE4MDlshAA)

---

P.S. You can now remove the defaults for your type parameters, and it'll still work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, explaining that it was due to lack of [partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) was a key insight for me. Instead of the currying solution, I am opting for a different solution that avoids the need for partial type inference altogether by passing the table as an argument. I will post that solution as a separate answer.